# attempt to index field ? (nil value)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am not sure where the problem is. Anyone know why?

```
function check(board, color, row, col)
--if same color, change tile to "o"

if board[row][col] == color then -- attempt to index nil?
    board[row][col] = "o"
    count = count + 1
    return "o"
end

return
```

end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `board[row]` is not defined; it's `nil`. So you are trying to do `nil[col]`.

You can avoid this error by doing this:

```
if board[row] and board[row][col] == color then
```

Instead.

However, I'd recommend you to review the way board is created - for example, make sure that you have not switched rows and cols somewhere in your code by mistake.