# Having an issue targeting an element of a table in a table Lua 5.2

Tags: lua

Probably a simple question but I'm new to lualang(5.2) and Im having an issue with my code here:

```
local petProductivity, petLeisure, petCommunication, petExercise, petDiet, petSleep

local pet = {petName, 
  mentalHealth = {petProductivity = 5, petLeisure = 5, petCommunication = 5, mentalHealthAverage}, 
  physicalHealth = {petExercise = 5, petDiet =5, petSleep = 5, physicalHealthAverage},
  speech = 0,}

local mentalHealthAverage = (pet[2][1] + pet[2][2] + pet[2][3]) /3
local physicalHealthAverage = (pet[3][1] + pet[3][2] + pet[3][3]) /3
```

My error looks like this: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)

Another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397117/attempt-to-index-field-nil-value) was created to tackle the same issue but their solutions were no help to me. Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: `local mentalHealthAverage = (pet.mentalHealth.petProductivity + pet.mentalHealth.petLeisure + pet.mentalHealth.petCommunication) /3`

Comment: wow, i thought I tried this, thx a lot egor!